# What's the importance of parallel eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, determinant

I'm studying eigenvectors. I read that if a matrix is symmetric and if the eigenvalues are real numbers, the eigenvectors will be perpendicular. However, I have no idea what it means (if anything) when a matrix's eigenvectors are parallel. I took a matrix, M, which I made up arbitrarily, used numpy to find eigenvectors, and plotted them. I found these vectors to be parallel. Likewise, I found the determinant to be -1.

My questions are:

1. Do parallel eigenvectors mean anything important?
2. What does a determinant of -1 mean? (I believe a determinant is a volume scaling factor, so perhaps det of -1 means an input is reflected about some axis...?)
3. Are 1 & 2 above related?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

M = np.array([[1,2],[2,3]])
eigVec1 = np.linalg.eig(M)[1][:,0]
eigVec2 = np.linalg.eig(M)[1][:,1]

e1 = [(eigVec1[0]+i,eigVec1[1]+i) for i in np.linspace(-3,3,100)]
e2 = [(eigVec2[0]+i,eigVec2[1]+i) for i in np.linspace(-3,3,100)]

plt.scatter([e1[i][0] for i in range(100)], [e1[i][1] for i in range(100)])
plt.scatter([e2[i][0] for i in range(100)], [e2[i][1] for i in range(100)]
```

[image: parellel eigenvector plot]

Edit1: I've actually supplied a number of different matrices, including symmetric ones. And the output is always parallel. So it seems something is wrong with my design. For context, what I aimed to do was find points (x,y) points along each of the eigenvectors and plot them. I'm not certain that my code is accomplishing this effect as every time parallel lines are produced.

Edit2: I identified my mistake in plotting. The below update addressed the situation:

```py
s1 = [(eigVec1[0]*i,eigVec1[1]*i) for i in np.linspace(-3,3,100)]
s2 = [(eigVec2[0]*i,eigVec2[1]*i) for i in np.linspace(-3,3,100)]
plt.scatter([s1[i][0] for i in range(100)], [s1[i][1] for i in range(100)])
plt.scatter([s2[i][0] for i in range(100)], [s2[i][1] for i in range(100)])
```

[image: Updated plot]

It appears that in my first attempt, I supplied the same slope (y=x) which passed through the points, A & B, respectively, where A & B were the eigenvectors of matrix M. Hence why the initial plot was parallel. In my correction, I used eigenvectors as the slope, where each line passed through the origin (0,0).

This mostly answers question 1, (I believe) that parallel eigenvectors are impossible, as they'd be the same vector.

I am still curious about what a determinant of -1 means and is it related to the eigenvectors? (In this case, they appear to be orthogonal.)

Comment: By definition, a nonzero vector $x$ is an eigenvector of an operator $A$ when there is some scalar $\lambda$ for which $Ax=\lambda x.$ Also by definition, two eigenvectors $x$ and $y$ are parallel when there is a scalar $\mu$ for which $y=\mu x.$ Apply $A$ to both sides of that equation and draw your conclusion.